# ENVI and Monteverdi(OTB) band selection for RGB image display

Tags: envi, orfeo-toolbox

I've been using Monteverdi 2 for satellite image processing for a while. I've just started using ENVI for classification because it is easy to use for classification purpose.

My question is very simple:

I've loaded a satellite image to Monteverdi and selected bands 5,4,3 as RGB and I've get true color image as shown below:

[image: monteverdi_RGB]

Then I've loaded the same image to ENVI and selected same bands as RGB and the result is something like this:

[image]

Why there is such difference occurs ? Does anybody has an explanation for this?

PS : I've tried other band combinations and found that in ENVI bands 6,5,4 are true color combination. But still I don't get it, Why same image has different band combinations in this two program ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Monteverdi the band numbering starts from '0' and not '1'.